# Why mail() function of PHP does not work?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have tried code like this.

```
mail($to,$subject,$body)
```

This function returns true but mail is not there in my inbox.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that? There's millions of potential reasons for this.

Comment: are you using local development environment? xampp, wamp, lamp ??

Answer (score 0):

Default php mail sender without proper configuration don't include in mail header additional information about sender and most of mail services put this kind of mails into spam folder. Look there.